# Python list to string conversion for true mismatch

Tags: python, string, list

The input

`rule = ['xor',[{'asset':'pc','operator':'=','basis':true}]]` ->

which is **type list**

**I want to convert the list to string**

Expected Output (rule):

**type string**  -> `"(['xor',[{'asset':'pc','operator':'=','basis':true}]])"`

I will use this further in the eval which expects string input

```
rule_out =  (eval(rule, {'true': True})
```

now rule_out becomes

```
rule_out = ['xor', [{'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '=', 'basis': True}]]
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. What is your question? What is the context in your question? Please provide a [mcve]. Also -- you are talking about taking a string which is pulled from a UI in some unspecified manner and sending it to some code on a backend which uses `eval`??? That is a major security red flag.

Comment: Your `rule` is not a valid Python list or other literal, so what does it even mean to convert it to a string? If it isn't a string literal, what is it? Is it a literal in some other programming language? If so, what?

Comment: Yes it is valid literal in Java script . I have to convert it to valid literal in Python

Comment: Are you are asking about how to write a JavaScript function to convert a JavaScript literal into a string? If so, why did you tag the question with `python` rather than `JavaScript`? What exactly is the link between JavaScript and Python here? Please provide the relevant context to the question.

Comment: true keyword is defined as true in JS and True in python hence the mismatch as pointed by Maurice Meyer below

Answer (score 1):

You could define variables to act like 'aliases':

```
# js-like variables
null = None
true = True
false = False

rule1_str = "['xor', [{'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '=', 'basis': true}]]"
rule2_str = "['xor', [{'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '=', 'basis': True}]]"
rule3_str = "['xor', [{'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '=', 'basis': null}]]"

rule1 = ['xor', [{'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '=', 'basis': true}]]
rule2 = ['xor', [{'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '=', 'basis': True}]]
rule3 = ['xor', [{'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '=', 'basis': null}]]

for rule in (rule1, rule2, rule3):
    rule_out = eval(str(rule))
    print(rule_out)

for rule in (rule1_str, rule2_str, rule3_str):
    rule_out = eval(rule)
    print(rule_out)
```

Out:

```
['xor', [{'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '=', 'basis': True}]]
['xor', [{'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '=', 'basis': True}]]
['xor', [{'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '=', 'basis': None}]]
['xor', [{'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '=', 'basis': True}]]
['xor', [{'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '=', 'basis': True}]]
['xor', [{'asset': 'pc', 'operator': '=', 'basis': None}]]
```

Comment: @Zaks: Edited, else wise I dont understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what is the scope of the alias is it file-wise or module wise

Comment: File-wise, but that's just an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . Simple solution but great ! Kudos

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `str()` function:

```
rule = ['xor',[{'asset':'pc','operator':'=','basis':true}]]

rule_str = str(rule)
```